# Regex match pattern plus rest of the string until next dot, comma or space

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Let's say I have a string `WORK-232-3213-2323`. Known possible case scenarios:

```
WORK-232-3213-2323, some text
WORK-232-3213-2323. some text
WORK-232-3213-2323.xlsx
WORK-232-3213-2323 some text
WORK-232-3213-2323/some text
```

Format `WORK-232-3213-2323-some text` may also occur, but there is no need to handle this case

My current regex is able to catch needed strings with `WORK-232-3213-2323` pattern, but as an output I get `-232-3213-2323`. How to make it so that it would catch `WORK-` in string plus rest of the text until next whitespace, dot, slash or comma?

Current regex: `WORK-(.*?)[\s]`

C#:

```
Regex pattern = new Regex("WORK-(.*?)[\s]");
string result = pattern.Match(myString).Groups[1].Value
```

Comment: Something around  `\bWORK(?:-[0-9]+)+` maybe. You are currently trying to retrieve capture group 1's value btw.

Comment: @"^(?'prefix'[^\d]+)(?'number'[^\s,\./]+)"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might use a match without using a capture group and use a negated character class excluding a comma, dot or whitspace char.

```
\bWORK-[^.,\s]+
```

- `\bWORK-` Match WORK preceded by a word boundary to prevent a partial match
- `[^.,\s]+` [Negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) to match 1+ times any char except `.` `,` or a whitspace char

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/AsFMxo/1)

```
string[] strings = { 
    "WORK-232-3213-2323, some text",
    "WORK-232-3213-2323. some text",
    "WORK-232-3213-2323.xlsx",
    "WORK-232-3213-2323 some text",
    "WORK-232-3213-2323/some text"
    };
string pattern = @"\bWORK-[^.,\s]+";
foreach (String s in strings) {
    Console.WriteLine(Regex.Match(s, pattern).Value);
}
```

Output

```
WORK-232-3213-2323
WORK-232-3213-2323
WORK-232-3213-2323
WORK-232-3213-2323
WORK-232-3213-2323/some
```

---

If you don't want to match the last line, you could use the capture group and match a `.` `,` or whitespace char after it

```
\b(WORK-[^.,\s\/]+)[.,\s]
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nGsIBs/1)

For example using the same example strings:

```
string pattern = @"\b(WORK-[^.,\s\/]+)[.,\s]";
foreach (String s in strings) {
    Console.WriteLine(Regex.Match(s, pattern).Groups[1].Value);
}
```

Output

```
WORK-232-3213-2323
WORK-232-3213-2323
WORK-232-3213-2323
WORK-232-3213-2323
```

Answer (score 3):

Looks to me you can use the following pattern to handle all your cases, also the one that may occur:

```
\bWORK(?:-[0-9]+)+
```

See an online [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cbWORK%28%3f%3a-%5b0-9%5d%2b%29%2b&i=WORK-232-3213-2323%2c+some+text%0d%0aWORK-232-3213-2323.+some+text%0d%0aWORK-232-3213-2323.xlsx%0d%0aWORK-232-3213-2323+some+text%0d%0aWORK-232-3213-2323%2fsome+text%0d%0aWORK-232-3213-2323-some+text)

I'm no hero in `c#` so I used some code I could find to test this:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var s = @"WORK-232-3213-2323, some text";
        var pattern = @"\bWORK(?:-[0-9]+)+";
        
        Regex r = new Regex(pattern);       
        
        Match m = r.Match(s);
        if (m.Success) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

---

Alternatively you can use `\bWORK(?:-\d+)+`  and use `Regex r = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.ECMAScript);` with the ECMAScript option set.